# Does it matter which floor I build in Tiny Death Star for supply and demand purposes?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

[I have seen answer question about Supply/Demand about Tiny Tower](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/54029/18818), but is this the same case in Tiny Death Star?

I ask this because in Tiny Death Star, it does not show demand percentages when I build a new floor, only quantity of all floors (So I do not think this is a duplicate of that question about).

What it looks like in Tiny Death Star when creating a new floor:

[image]

What it looks like in Tiny Tower when creating a new floor:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there should be balance in the floors to keep demand high. They did mention this in Tiny Death Star too.

Comment: Where do they mention this?

Comment: This could use some elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that they mentioned it either in the tutorial, like when they were explaining how to build levels, or in one of the earlier missions when you have to build a certain level, he said "to keep the demand up" or something along those lines.